# File Transfer: show file size 0KB while transferring file using smack in Android

Tags: android, xmpp, file-transfer, openfire, smack

Getting Problem while file transfer in android using Smack library and open-fire Server,Empty file is received on other device while transferring file one device to another,its show the 0KB size.when i opened it,its shows blank screen.i does not know what's the problem behind it.

I am using [this link](http://harryjoy.com/2012/08/18/file-transfer-in-android-with-asmack-and-openfire/) for Implementing.My Code is:

```
public void ReceiveFile() {

    ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

    if (sdm == null)``
    {
        sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);
        Log.e("service discovery", "SDM");
    sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");

    sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");
    }

    FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
    Log.e("after manager", "manager");
    manager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
       public void fileTransferRequest(final FileTransferRequest request) {
          new Thread(){
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 Log.e("Thread running", "starting");
                IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
                File mf = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                Log.e("path", mf.getAbsoluteFile()+"/DCIM/" + transfer.getFileName());
                File file = new File(mf.getAbsoluteFile()+"/DCIM/" + transfer.getFileName());

                try{
                    transfer.recieveFile(file);
                    while(!transfer.isDone()) {
                       try{
                          Thread.sleep(1000L);
                       }catch (Exception e) {
                          Log.e("", e.getMessage());
                       }
                       if(transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.error)) {
                          Log.e("ERROR!!! ", transfer.getError() + "");
                       }
                       if(transfer.getException() != null) {
                          transfer.getException().printStackTrace();
                          Log.e("not null", "print stack success");
                       }
                    }
                 }catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("", e.getMessage());
                }
             };
           }.start();
        }
     });



}

public void sndFile(final String path, final String receiver) {
    ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

    if (sdm == null)
    {
        sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(connection);
        Log.e("service discovery", "SDM");
    sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");

    sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");
    }

    FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);
    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(receiver+"/Smack");
    File file = new File(path);
    try {
       transfer.sendFile(file, "test_file");
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(!transfer.isDone()) {
       if(transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.error)) {
          System.out.println("ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());
          Log.e("while status error", "error");

       } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.refused)
                        || transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)) {
          System.out.println("Cancelled!!! " + transfer.getError());
          Log.e("while Cancelled", "cancel refuse");
       }
       try {
          Thread.sleep(1000L);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    if(transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.refused) || transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.error)
     || transfer.getStatus().equals(org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)){
       System.out.println("refused cancelled error " + transfer.getError());
       Log.e("if cancelled", "refused cancel");

    } else {
       System.out.println("Success");
       Log.e("if no error", "Success");
       j=0;
       arrList_messages.add("File "+transfer.getFileName()+"Sent");
       arrList_messages.add(" ");
       setListAdapter();
     setListAdapterGreen();
    }


}
```

My LogCat While sending:

```
07-12 12:45:47.330: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22548): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-12 12:45:57.511: I/Path:(22548): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_2013-07-08-13-08-57.png
07-12 12:45:57.514: I/Started(22548):  Applicationtrue
07-12 12:45:57.515: I/Resumed(22548):  Applicationtrue
07-12 12:45:59.560: W/System.err(22548): java.lang.InterruptedException
07-12 12:45:59.561: W/System.err(22548):    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1198)
07-12 12:45:59.561: W/System.err(22548):    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:311)
07-12 12:45:59.561: W/System.err(22548):    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.put(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:292)
07-12 12:45:59.561: W/System.err(22548):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter.sendPacket(PacketWriter.java:97)
07-12 12:45:59.561: W/System.err(22548):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.sendPacket(XMPPConnection.java:488)
07-12 12:45:59.561: W/System.err(22548):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.Socks5TransferNegotiator.negotiateIncomingStream(Socks5TransferNegotiator.java:130)
07-12 12:45:59.562: W/System.err(22548):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FaultTolerantNegotiator$NegotiatorService.call(FaultTolerantNegotiator.java:181)
07-12 12:45:59.562: W/System.err(22548):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FaultTolerantNegotiator$NegotiatorService.call(FaultTolerantNegotiator.java:166)
07-12 12:45:59.562: W/System.err(22548):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-12 12:45:59.562: W/System.err(22548):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-12 12:45:59.562: W/System.err(22548):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
07-12 12:45:59.562: W/System.err(22548):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-12 12:45:59.562: W/System.err(22548):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-12 12:45:59.562: W/System.err(22548):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-12 12:45:59.562: W/System.err(22548):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-12 12:45:59.562: W/System.err(22548):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

My LogCat While Receving:

```
06-19 11:22:41.912: W/System.err(15386): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
06-19 11:22:41.912: W/System.err(15386):   -- caused by: No response from remote client: 
06-19 11:22:41.913: W/System.err(15386):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:233)
06-19 11:22:41.913: W/System.err(15386):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:90)
06-19 11:22:41.913: W/System.err(15386):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer.negotiateStream(IncomingFileTransfer.java:193)
06-19 11:22:41.913: W/System.err(15386):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer.access$100(IncomingFileTransfer.java:47)
06-19 11:22:41.913: W/System.err(15386):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer$1.run(IncomingFileTransfer.java:124)
06-19 11:22:41.913: W/System.err(15386):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-19 11:22:41.913: W/System.err(15386):   -- caused by: No response from remote client: 
06-19 11:22:41.914: W/System.err(15386):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FaultTolerantNegotiator.createIncomingStream(FaultTolerantNegotiator.java:113)
06-19 11:22:41.914: W/System.err(15386):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer$2.call(IncomingFileTransfer.java:186)
06-19 11:22:41.914: W/System.err(15386):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer$2.call(IncomingFileTransfer.java:183)
06-19 11:22:41.914: W/System.err(15386):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-19 11:22:41.914: W/System.err(15386):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-19 11:22:41.914: W/System.err(15386):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer.negotiateStream(IncomingFileTransfer.java:190)
06-19 11:22:41.914: W/System.err(15386):    ... 3 more
06-19 11:22:41.914: E/not null(15386): print stack success
06-19 11:22:41.914: E/ERROR!!!(15386): null
```

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712671/smack-no-response-from-server-not-sure-why-am-i-getting-this-error ? It seems that your connection is getting interrupted, may be because of weak connection or some other.

Comment: Hi there, did you solve the problem? i am facing the same problem as yours.

Comment: @HarryJoy I followed your tutorial and tried to share file. I am able to send file but facing problem in receiving file. Can you see over this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28271210/4358880) and tell what mistake i am making?

Comment: @nitish have you solved your issue ? I am facing same issue.

Comment: I am sending and receiving files using [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378423/file-transfer-not-working-smack-4-1-android/33994755#33994755)