# File Transfer not working smack 4.1 android

Tags: android, file-transfer, smack

Currently I am playing around with the new Smack 4.1 that offers full support for android. Sending and receiving messages is no problem, works fine. But now, I get stuck on sending and receiving Files. For example:

### Send File

```
public void sendFile(String fileName,String to){

        if(transferManager==null) {
            transferManager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);

        }


        OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = transferManager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(to);

        try {

            transfer.sendFile(new File(fileName), "This is a Test!");
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

### Receive files

```
 public void setReceiveFileListener(){


        if(transferManager==null) {
            transferManager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
        }
        transferManager.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
            @Override
            public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {
                IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();

                try {
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + File.separator +"TEST"+File.separator+ "new.txt");
                    transfer.recieveFile(file);

                } catch (SmackException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });

    }
```

In this scenario, I just send a text file and want to save it as a new text file at sd card as "new.txt". The problem is not with the file itself, the file exists. Also, the receiver id is correct, it´s like "user@host.com/Smack" . That´s the same receiver which I can send normal messages successfully.

### The error code I get from Smack:

**error 503 - service unavailable**

This error respone I get directly from smack after sending file and it seems the file is not transferred, because the receiver listener shows nothing (I made Logs on both, sending and receiving), but listener is surely registerred.
But I am totally sure, that File Transfer is supported by the server, it´s declared at their website www.coderollers.com . I´ve read many questions about here in SO and also at the Smack Developer Community. Nothing helped, so my question here is:

1. What could be the cause of this problem?
2. Could it be because I have to change the Port?
3. How to change the port of an existing connection in smack?
4. Any alternatives to file transport?

My normal port is 5222, that works fine to send messages. I hope someone get it work and can lead me to the right directions....thanks for helping!

### SOLUTION

For all who are interested: Devendra Singhs answer is correct, with a little note by myself. It seems to be important, which resource is used. From mobile to mobile, You have to use **"mobile"**. Wether "Smack" nor any other resource identifier would work here. So it is important to initialize the `OutgoingFileTransfer` correctly like this:

```
        OutgoingFileTransfer oft = ftm1.createOutgoingFileTransfer
(XmppStringUtils.completeJidFrom(USER, SERV, "mobile"));//important resource "mobile"
```

Comment: did you find any solution? @Opitaetuchs

Comment: no, unfortunnately not. I went to transfer my files via my own server...I guess that this error is caused by the different implemantations on server side. Not all servers supporting file transfer. I think You have to look into the features from the server You used..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it after very research.

```
FileTransferManager ftm1 = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    FileTransferManager ftm2 = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection2);

    ftm2.addFileTransferListener(new FileTransferListener() {
        @Override
        public void fileTransferRequest(FileTransferRequest request) {
            IncomingFileTransfer ift = request.accept();
            try {
                InputStream is = ift.recieveFile();
                ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int nRead;
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                while ((nRead = is.read(buf,  0, buf.length)) != -1) {
                    os.write(buf, 0, nRead);
                }
                os.flush();
                dataReceived = os.toByteArray();
            } catch (SmackException | IOException | XMPPErrorException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (Arrays.equals(dataToSend, dataReceived)) {
                System.out.println("Received data matches send data. \\o/");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Recieved data DOES NOT match send data. :(");
            }
        }
    });

    OutgoingFileTransfer oft = ftm1.createOutgoingFileTransfer(XmppStringUtils.completeJidFrom(USER, SERV, "resourse"));
    oft.sendStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(dataToSend), "hello.txt", dataToSend.length, "A greeting");
    outerloop: while (!oft.isDone()) {
        switch (oft.getStatus()) {
        case error:
            System.out.println("Filetransfer error: " + oft.getError());
            break outerloop;
        default:
            System.out.println("Filetransfer status: " + oft.getStatus() + ". Progress: " + oft.getProgress());
            break;
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    connection.disconnect();
    connection2.disconnect();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

the one connection is sending file and another connection is receiving this is working code.

Comment: which xmpp server You are using?

Comment: ok thanks. I will give it a try, if it works, You get my upvote...sorry need a little bit time :)

Comment: tried it now, sending seems to be ok because I put some Log into switch case and it works without error. But receiving is not working....very strange..

Comment: got it...turns out that it is very important which resource is selected. In Your example it is "receiver", but from mobile to mobile it is "mobile". No "Smack", No "receiver" or something else. If You change this in Your answer to lead all with the same problem into right direction, I will vote up and set it as correct answer.

Comment: to get complete jid from the method we have to provide some resource so i provide that and it is working yet. you can improve it. even i was getting the error you are facing **service unavailable**but not now.

Comment: progress  keep on 0.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, I investigated the stanza and solved it this way.

Many people use **"/Smack**" or **"/Resource"** as resource part in jid, but that can be done another way.

Resource path is changing with every presence changed of user. Lets say we want to send image to this user:
**"user1@mydomain"**

You must add "/Resource" or "/Smack" part to this jid and it become this:
**user1@mydomain/Resource**

But resource path is changing with presence so you must follow every presence change to update resource path.
Best way is to get user presence is in roster listener and in presencheChanged() method you get last user resource part like this:

```
Roster roster=getRoster();
roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
                @Override
                public void entriesAdded(Collection<Jid> addresses) {
                    Log.d("entriesAdded", "ug");
                    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("ENTRIES_ADDED"));
                }

                @Override
                public void entriesUpdated(Collection<Jid> addresses) {
                    Log.d("entriesUpdated", "ug");
                }

                @Override
                public void entriesDeleted(Collection<Jid> addresses) {
                    Log.d("entriesDeleted", "ug");
                }

                @Override
                public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
                    Log.d("presenceChanged", "ug");
                    //Resource from presence
                    String resource = presence.getFrom().getResourceOrEmpty().toString();
                    //Update resource part for user in DB or preferences
                    //...
                }
            });
}
```

Resource string will be some generated string like **"6u1613j3kv**" and jid will become:
**user1@mydomain/6u1613j3kv**

That means that you must create your outgoing transfer like this:

```
EntityFullJid jid = JidCreate.entityFullFrom("user1@mydomain/6u1613j3kv"); 
OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(jid)
```

In your case this resource part is **"mobile"**. Just change it with resource part from presence in roster listener.

And that is how i have solved my problem with file transfer on smack and Openfire.

Also to mention you must add following properties in your Openfire server:

```
xmpp.proxy.enabled - true
xmpp.proxy.externalip - MY_IP_ADDRESS
xmpp.proxy.port -7777
```

Just to mention, I am using Openfire 4.0.2 and Smack 4.2.2.

Also this can be configured the easy way, just set the resource on

> XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder .

like

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configurationBuilder = 
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder(); 

configurationBuilder.setResource("yourResourceName");
```