# Openfire , xep-0363 http file upload support

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

guys.

currently, I'm using a modified version of Xabber client and for file transfer it uses xep-0363. but it seems that openfire does not support this extension.
is there any way to add this capability to openfire. ??

if not what are the alternatives ?? which servers support this kind of file transfer protocol ??

Thanks in advance
MA.

Comment: xep-0363 it's Experimental, so you have to develop it as plugin for Openfire if you want to... however look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378423/file-transfer-not-working-smack-4-1-android

Answer (score 1):

I used open fire for messaging. What i did was used my own server for uploading/downloading files and using  the links from server in message body (message body as json) and differentiated msgs using message type.
These msgs are sent via xmpp/openfire.

normal message would look like `{msg_type:"text",msg:"Hello"}`
image message would look like `{msg_type:"image",msg:"www.myservewr.com/192/image.jpg"}`

Delivery manager will trigger whenever a message is delivered.

```
  DeliveryReceiptManager dm = DeliveryReceiptManager
                            .getInstanceFor(connection);
                    dm.autoAddDeliveryReceiptRequests();
                    dm.setAutoReceiptMode(DeliveryReceiptManager.AutoReceiptMode.always);
                    dm.addReceiptReceivedListener(new ReceiptReceivedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onReceiptReceived(final String fromid,
                                                      final String toid, final String msgid,
                                                      final Stanza packet) {
                            System.out.println("DElivery success!");
}
```

Comment: thanks buddy for your suggestion. if I could handle this by the functionality of Openfire server it would be great. a long time ago I implemented this  by using `FileTransferManager` of Smack library. I suppose it worth to implement this again in order to use `DeliveryReceiptManager`

Comment: DeliveryReceiptManager can be used in both scenarios. FileTransferManger is a very slow compared to other when i used it months ago

Comment: can explain more , how can I  use DeliveryReceiptManager in your method ??

Comment: DeliveryRecieptManager triggers whenever u sent a message and its received at the other end .. whether its a normal message or a file or anything. So u can upload a file to ur server then sent that link a message and once it reaches the other side u will get ACK. See updated answer

Comment: if I understand well, I will get ACK when the message (containing download link) is received. but not when the file is downloaded at the other side. am I true ?? if

Comment: yes. but u can send custom packet using xmpp to send a message to indicate file is downloaded