# File sending using smack 4.2.4

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack, instant-messaging

I’m trying to send image and file using smack 4.2.4 and my server is jabb3r.org but without any process, it sends me this error :

> > XMPP error reply received from fattaneh123@jabb3r.org/Xabber_egtxJrjU: XMPPError: service-unavailable - wait

I've test the file sending feature in xabber and chat secure,and they work properly with the jabb3r but they upload file on proxy.hot-chilli.net:5281/upload
how could I access this url and send my file

```
public void send(String id, String path) throws XmppStringprepException{
        ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        if (sdm == null) {
            sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");
            sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");
        }
        FileTransferManager manager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        final OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(JidCreate.entityFullFrom("fattaneh123@jabb3r.org/Xabber_egtxJrjU"));


        FileTransferNegotiator.IBB_ONLY = true;

        final File file = new File(path);
        try {
            FileTransferNegotiator.getInstanceFor(connection).negotiateOutgoingTransfer(JidCreate.entityFullFrom("fattaneh123@jabb3r.org/Xabber_egtxJrjU"), transfer.getStreamID(), file.getName(), file.length(), "ali", 10000);
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileTransferException.NoAcceptableTransferMechanisms noAcceptableTransferMechanisms) {
            noAcceptableTransferMechanisms.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {


            protected void onPreExecute() {

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    transfer.sendFile(file,file.getName());
                } catch (SmackException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while (!transfer.isDone()) {
                    if (transfer.getStatus().equals("Error")) {
                        Log.d("file transfer",
                                "ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());

                    } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals("Cancelled")
                            || transfer.getStatus().equals("Refused")) {
                        Log.d("file transfer",
                                "Cancelled!!! " + transfer.getError());
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                if (transfer.getStatus().equals("Refused")
                        || transfer.getStatus().equals("Error")
                        || transfer.getStatus().equals("Cancelled")) {
                    Log.i("file transfer", "refused cancelled error "
                            + transfer.getError());

                } else {

                    Log.i("file transfer", "Success: " + transfer.getException().getMessage());
                }
            }

            ;
        }.execute();

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Transfer not working smack 4.1 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378423/file-transfer-not-working-smack-4-1-android)

Comment: Is your resource for client "Xabber_egtxJrjU" correct? Also check if your smack service/application is running on other client that is receiving the file.

Comment: File sending in smack with xmpp server not recommended. Because it need that sender and receiver be online and available. It's better to implement your own to upload file to your sever and just send the url or file name with xmpp messages to each other.