# Error code 503 on transferring file using xmpp

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am trying to send an image file using smack and openfire xmpp. For this I am using FileTransferManager class. To use FileTransferManager class I am using *asmack-android-6.jar*. I followed this [link](http://harryjoy.com/2012/08/18/file-transfer-in-android-with-asmack-and-openfire/) to do file sharing. This issue is also shared in comments below on this tutorial but no good resolution is given to this issue. Then I searched over stack overflow, Many Developers have asked this question but only 1-2 have got replies that they have accepted, [others](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17921288/4358880) not.

I studied all the answers that I found, tried all the ways that google gave me but still unable to solve this problem.

The code I used is:

```
d.findViewById(R.id.btnsendphoto).setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if (!filepath.equals("")) {
                                ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager
                                        .getInstanceFor(connection);

                                if (sdm == null) {
                                    sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(
                                            connection);
                                    Log.e("service discovery", "SDM");
                                    sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");

                                    sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");
                                }

                                mFileTransferManager = new FileTransferManager(
                                        connection);
                                /*
                                 * OutgoingFileTransfer transfer =
                                 * mFileTransferManager
                                 * .createOutgoingFileTransfer
                                 * ("98c6d889473a6fae@pc/Smack");
                                 */
                                String to = connection.getRoster()
                                        .getPresence("98c6d889473a6fae@pc")
                                        .getFrom();
                                OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = mFileTransferManager
                                        .createOutgoingFileTransfer(to);
                                File file = new File(filepath);

                                try {
//[configureProviderManager](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9932239/)
                                    configureProviderManager(connection);
                                    transfer.sendFile(file, "test_file");
                                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                while(!transfer.isDone()) {
                                    Log.d("status", transfer.getStatus().toString());
                                    Log.d("percent", new Long(transfer.getBytesSent()).toString());
                                    if (transfer.getStatus() == Status.error) {
                                        Log.e("percent", "Error " + new Long(transfer.getBytesSent()).toString() + " " + transfer.getError() + " " + transfer.getException());
                                        transfer.cancel();

                                    }

                                    if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.refused))
                                             System.out.println("refused  " + transfer.getError());
                                    else if( transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error))
                                         System.out.println(" error " + transfer.getError());
                                    else if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.cancelled))
                                       System.out.println(" cancelled  " + transfer.getError());
                                    else
                                       System.out.println("Success");



                                }

                            }
                            d.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
```

The [logcat](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9932105/) I got is very big, so I gave link of that. So can anyone tell what mistake I am making or can suggest what amendment I make to achieve task

Comment: I'd like to help, but all I can do is to point at https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-XMPP-File-Transfer

Comment: ok I study the link you gave, thanks for commenting

Comment: @Flow I read the link you gave but i haven't found solution for my problem there

Comment: The content of the linked page basically tries to tell you that you should be able to solve the problem yourself. Because since Smack is open source and XMPP is an open standard you can debug and analyze the cause for the failing file transfer yourself.

Comment: i am not able to reply this comment, but still thanks, you gave your precious time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem got solved using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26772599/3409600) answer don't know why its downvoted. Lemme share answer here also

```
d.findViewById(R.id.btnsendphoto).setOnClickListener(
                    new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if (!filepath.equals("")) {
                                ServiceDiscoveryManager sdm = ServiceDiscoveryManager
                                        .getInstanceFor(connection);

                                if (sdm == null) {
                                    sdm = new ServiceDiscoveryManager(
                                            connection);
                                    Log.e("service discovery", "SDM");
                                    sdm.addFeature("http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info");

                                    sdm.addFeature("jabber:iq:privacy");
                                }
                                configureProviderManager(connection);
                                FileTransferNegotiator.IBB_ONLY = true;
                                FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);
                                mFileTransferManager = new FileTransferManager(
                                        connection);
                                /*
                                 * OutgoingFileTransfer transfer =
                                 * mFileTransferManager
                                 * .createOutgoingFileTransfer
                                 * ("98c6d889473a6fae@pc/Smack");
                                 */
                                String to = connection.getRoster()
                                        .getPresence("98c6d889473a6fae@pc")
                                        .getFrom();
                                final OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = mFileTransferManager
                                        .createOutgoingFileTransfer(to);
                                File file = new File(filepath);

                                try {
                                    configureProviderManager(connection);
                                    transfer.sendFile(file, "test_file");
                                } catch (XMPPException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {


                                    protected void onPreExecute() {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                        while (!transfer.isDone()) {
                                            if (transfer.getStatus().equals("Error")) {
                                                Log.d("file transfer",
                                                        "ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());

                                            } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals("Cancelled")
                                                    || transfer.getStatus().equals("Refused")) {
                                                Log.d("file transfer",
                                                        "Cancelled!!! " + transfer.getError());
                                            }
                                            try {
                                                Thread.sleep(1000L);
                                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                    };

                                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                                        if (transfer.getStatus().equals("Refused")
                                                || transfer.getStatus().equals("Error")
                                                || transfer.getStatus().equals("Cancelled")) {
                                            Log.i("file transfer", "refused cancelled error "
                                                    + transfer.getError());

                                        } else {

                                            Log.i("file transfer", "Success: " + transfer.getFileName());
                                        }
                                    };
                                }.execute();

                            }
                            d.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: where is the configureProviderManager(connection) implemented?

Comment: Please provide configureProviderManager(connection) complete, i have issue with this methods, please share this

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I investigated the stanza and solved it this way.

Many people use **"/Smack"** or **"/Resource"** as resource part in jid, but it can be configured also the another way.

Resource path is changing with every presence changed of user. Lets say we want to send image to this user:
**"user1@mydomain"**

You must add **"/Resource"** part to this jid and it become this:
**user1@mydomain/Resource**

But **/Resource** path is changing with presence so you must follow every presence change to update resource path.
Best way is to get user presence is in roster listener and in presencheChanged() method you get last user resource part like this:

```
Roster roster=getRoster();
roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
                @Override
                public void entriesAdded(Collection<Jid> addresses) {
                    Log.d("entriesAdded", "ug");
                    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("ENTRIES_ADDED"));
                }

                @Override
                public void entriesUpdated(Collection<Jid> addresses) {
                    Log.d("entriesUpdated", "ug");
                }

                @Override
                public void entriesDeleted(Collection<Jid> addresses) {
                    Log.d("entriesDeleted", "ug");
                }

                @Override
                public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
                    Log.d("presenceChanged", "ug");
                    //Resource from presence
                    String resource = presence.getFrom().getResourceOrEmpty().toString();
                    //Update resource part for user in DB or preferences
                    //...
                }
            });
}
```

Resource string will be some generated string like "6u1613j3kv" and jid will become:

```
user1@mydomain/6u1613j3kv
```

That means that you must create your outgoing transfer like this:

```
EntityFullJid jid = JidCreate.entityFullFrom("user1@mydomain/6u1613j3kv"); 
OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(jid)
transfer.sendFile(new File("DirectoryPath"), "Description");
```

And that is how i have solved my problem with file transfer on smack and Openfire.

In your case form **jid** like this:

```
String to = connection.getRoster().getPresence("98c6d889473a6fae@pc").getFrom();
String Resource = connection.getRoster().getPresence("98c6d889473a6fae@pc").getFrom().getResourceOrEmpty().toString();
OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = mFileTransferManager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(to + "/" + resource);
```

Also to mention you must add following properties in your Openfire server:

```
xmpp.proxy.enabled - true
xmpp.proxy.externalip - MY_IP_ADDRESS
xmpp.proxy.port - 7777
```

Just to mention, I am using Openfire 4.0.2 and Smack 4.2.2.

Also this can be configured the easy way, just set the resource on

> XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder .

like

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configurationBuilder = 
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder(); 

configurationBuilder.setResource("yourResourceName");
```